# Most efficient way to store used IPs by a user using mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am in need to collect all IP addresses used by a user, but i am not sure what the best way is.

One way to solve this issue is, to have a table which will contain records about user logins with what IP. On each sign in, insert a record that associate a userID with an IP.

Then on user ban, i will look through all the records in table and blacklist these IPs.

But it feels like unnecessary work, maybe just collect the ip addresses add them in an field of the user table? if this solution is more efficient, what datatype to use for that field and how should the stored data be formated?

Comment: INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA()

Comment: Careful! Storing IP addresses counts as storing personal information on a user according to the EU's GDPR https://www.whitecase.com/publications/alert/court-confirms-ip-addresses-are-personal-data-some-cases

Make sure you can easily anonymise the data once its stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like the most efficient method,

Store all IPS on a separate database, with known users that used it.

Then you may blacklist those IPs base on who you're trying to ban. All you need to lookup is all IPs that was previously used by xx